# GitLab masterブランチ以外のPUSHで Piplineが実行されない。

Tags: gitlab

GitLabにてCIのテストを実施しています。
.gitlab-ci.ymlを以下のように編集しています。
[image: gitlab-ci.yml]

masterブランチにファイルをPUSHしたら正常にJOBが起動されるのですが
test2ブランチにファイルをPUSHしてもJOBは実行されません・・・。
試しに`only`を外してみたのですが、結果は同じでした・・・。
どうすればmasterブランチ以外のブランチでもJOBを起動することができるでしょうか？ 
私としては新規ブランチをPUSHした場合でもJOBを実行したいです。

ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします・・・。

==追記==
先ほどGitLabの**Run Pipline**で Create for にtest2ブランチを選択したら以下のように怒られました。`.gitlab_ci.yml`は確かにないのですが、ファイル配置は各ブランチで必要ということでしょうか・・・？
[image: エラー画面]
ちなみにtest2ブランチにGitLab上で`.gitlab_ci.yml`を追加したらJOBは起動しました・・・。

新規ブランチを`push`した場合、わざわざGitLab上で`.gitlab_ci.yml`を追加しないとJOBは実行されないということでしょうか・・・？

==追記2==
gitlabサーバーで直接xxxx.gitディレクトリ直下に`.gitlab_ci.yml`を追加しましたが
動きませんでした・・・。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決ができた気がします。
私の認識が誤っていた気がします。[One `.gitlab-ci.yml` per branch or per repository?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20873)

を読む限り、リポジトリ：gitlab-ci.yml＝1:1ではなく、ブランチ:gitlab-ci.yml ＝1:1
なんですね。

確かにmasterに配置したgitlab-ci.ymlをベースにブランチを作成する事でgitlab-ci.ymlが配置されていきました。
お騒がせしました・・・。

そうなると`only`や`except`って基本中の基本で、各ブランチによってカスタマイズ可能
ってなるから、存在意義が薄い気がしますが・・・。そうでもないもんですかね。